# Does the Nintendo Switch not adjust to your TV's aspect ratio?

Tags: nintendo-switch

Just bought my Nintendo Switch, but when I tried docking it to the TV and the image was much larger than the TV screen. When I tried adjusting it, I had to make the screen so small that there were two black bars on either end of the picture.

I'm using a standard 16:9 HDTV and I would imagine that it would have automatically adjusted itself to work on my TV without needing black bars on the ends.

Comment: Some games let you resize the screen to make sure that you can see the entire screen on your tv.

Answer (score 3):

Please check your TV's display mode. It's possible your TV is set to stretch or zoom the image. If that's the case, the Switch is sending the signal right but your TV is overriding it.